# Слить два столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

"a" и "b" два столбца датафрейма, как их объединить?

```
a b

0 10
1 1
1 0
0 5
5 0 
0 0
0 0
```

Результат:

```
a b   с 

0 10  10
1 1   1
1 0   1
0 5   5
5 0   5 
0 0   0
0 0   0
```

Comment: каким образом из исходных `0 0` получилось `1 1   1` во второй строке??

Comment: Может максимум из двух столбцов?

Comment: может быть, но тогда в исходном фрейме - опечатка

Comment: df['c'] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda row: max(row), axis=1)

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, так делать не надо - это очень медленный вариант. Вариант от CrazyElf - будет работать __гораздо__ быстрее)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('ff.csv')

df['c'] = df[['a','b']].max(axis=1)

df[(df.a > 0) | (df.b > 0)]
```

Вывод:

```
            a          b            c
13  45.843750   0.000000    45.843750
44  0.000000    43.281250   43.281250
69  45.812500   0.000000    45.812500
85  0.000000    44.218750   44.218750
134 46.593750   0.000000    46.593750
147 0.000000    44.812500   44.812500
165 47.156250   0.000000    47.156250
.....................................
```

Вывожу только строки не с нулями в обеих колонках сразу, потому что в остальных строках нули и ничего интересного.

Comment: @Valent Стоп, так у вас там не нули, а `NaN`? И какой тип столбцов ещё хотелось бы узнать. А то вдруг один `int`, а другой `string/object`.

Comment: @Valent Хотя я попробовал, с `NaN` прекрасно работает.

Comment: @Valent Приведите пример ваших данных и где тот код, который я привёл, выдаёт неправильный результат. Это очень странно.

Comment: @Valent, приведите в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных

Comment: @Valent И на вашем файле тоже всё прекрасно работает

Comment: @CrazyElf, подтверждаю)